# Modify all linked instances

Tags: linked-data

It seems that inherited attributes that can be overridden is needed in Blender for objects considering its complexity. In any event, I thought I read that linked objects only have location and rotations unique to each instance, which would accomplish the same thing for me. But when I change the dimensions of one, the others do not change. I also tried this after having made the two objects reference the same mesh. Is there a way to edit the dimensions of all the linked objects at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a copy of an object and add a *Copy Scale* constraint with the original object as a target.

[image]

Duplicated objects will have that constraint. To copy this constraint to existing objects, select them, make sure the object with the constraint is active, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks! (Although that key combination doesn't work for me.)